# How can I compare two values in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a container which can persist values of different types implementing the `Comparable` interface. I need to compare those values as follows:

```
UpperLowerContainer values;
//initializing the container
Comparable<?> upper = (Comparable<?>) values.getUpper();
Comparable<?> lower = (Comparable<?>) values.getLower();
if (upper.compareTo(lower) < 0){ //This is not compiled
    //do some
}
```

The code is not compiled because of the obvious reason. The capture of the `lower`'s wildcard cannot be cast to the capture of `upper`'s wildacrd and vice versa.

But how can I solve that issue? Any idea?

UPD: The type of the values stored in the container are the same. There is a validation before storing them into it.

Comment: Comparable<CLASSNAME> upper = (Comparable<CLASSNAME>) values.getUpper();
  Comparable<CLASSNAME> lower = (Comparable<CLASSNAME>) values.getLower();

try casting the as if (upper.compareTo((CLASSNAME)lower)

Comment: classname can be date as well as integer

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're asking is possible.  You're asking to compare potentially incomparable objects together.  Having some more code would round out the actual issue, as while I think the other answers touch on the compilation, they're not sussing out the root problem.

Comment: Although you have to teel JVM what class you are going to compare, If your class is Integer use :
Comparable<Integer> upper = (Comparable<Integer>) values.getUpper(); Comparable<Integer> lower = (Comparable<Integer>) values.getLower(); 
if (upper.compareTo((Integer)lower)

Answer (score 0):

What does your class `UpperLowerContainer` look like? You could use type arguments, so that you do not need to use wildcards and casts. For example:

```
public class UpperLowerContainer<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private final T lower;
    private final T upper;

    public UpperLowerContainer(T lower, T upper) {
        this.lower = lower;
        this.upper = upper;
    }

    public T getLower() {
        return lower;
    }

    public T getUpper() {
        return upper;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Comparable<T> upper = values.getUpper();
Comparable<T> lower = values.getLower();
if (upper.compareTo(lower) < 0) {
    // do something
}
```

The reason why it doesn't work is because the compiler can't be sure that the two wildcards in these lines refer to the same type:

```
Comparable<?> upper = (Comparable<?>) values.getUpper();
Comparable<?> lower = (Comparable<?>) values.getLower();
```

If you call `compareTo` on one of those comparables, you have to pass it a value of the same type. However, because type type is unknown, there's no way for the compiler to check if you pass a value of the right type, so you get an error.

Comment: It's just a container returning `Object`s. I can't modify it in the way you proposed.

Comment: Probably I made some architectural mistake and got into those troubles. Is there a way to ix that without modifying the container?

Comment: What exactly do `values.getUpper()` and `values.getLower()` return? The raw type `Comparable`? You could try using `Comparable<Object>` instead of `Comparable<?>`.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 0):

Given code will not compile until you will not specify type of object. You can not use wild cards as you are trying to use.
 class declaration should be:

```
public class UpperLowerContainer<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

and you should use like

```
Comparable<T> upper = values.getUpper();
Comparable<T> lower = values.getLower();
```

now you code

```
if (upper.compareTo(lower) < 0) {
    // do something
}
```

will compile

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`