# Why can't we capture wildcards for the method with two parameters?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Related to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702934/how-can-i-compare-two-values-in-java) question.

I know about wildcard capturing. For instance, the following could be used for reversing a list:

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list) { rev(list); } //capturing the wildcard
private static <T> void rev(List<T> list) {
    List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<T>(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, tmp.get(list.size()-i-1));
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to write the same thing for that kind of situation:

```
private int compare (Comparable<?> upper, Comparable<?> lower){
    return comp(upper, lower);  //The method comp(Comparable<T>, Comparable<T>) is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable<capture#5-of ?>, Comparable<capture#6-of ?>)
}

private <T> int comp(Comparable<T> upper, Comparable<T> lower){
    return upper.compareTo((T) lower);
}
```

I expected that it was compiled fine as well. Is it possible to capture wildacrds for methods with two or more parameters that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this method

```
private <T> int comp(Comparable<T> upper, Comparable<T> lower){
    return upper.compareTo((T) lower);
}
```

both of the parameters share the same type-parameter.

Meanwhile, this is not true for the other method:

```
private int compare (Comparable<?> upper, Comparable<?> lower){
    return comp(upper, lower); 
}
```

Here, the compiler has no evidence that the type-parameters for `upper` and `lower` are the same and that's why refuses to give green light to compilation.

If you want both of the methods to share the same type-parameter(s), you can make the type-parameter **class-scoped**. For example:

```
public class YourClass<T> {
     private int comp(Comparable<T> upper, Comparable<T> lower){
         return upper.compareTo((T) lower);
     }

     private int compare (Comparable<T> upper, Comparable<T> lower){
         return comp(upper, lower); 
     }
}
```

Another option (if you don't like the first one) would be to introduce one and the same upper bound for the type-parameters for `comp()` and `compare()`. For example:

```
private <T extends SomeSuperClass> int comp(Comparable<T> upper, Comparable<T> lower){
    return upper.compareTo((T) lower);
}

private <T extends SomeSuperClass> int compare (Comparable<T> upper, Comparable<T> lower){
    return comp(upper, lower); 
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to avoid the casting in the `comp()` method, you can do:

```
public class YourClass<T extends SomeSuperClass & Comparable<T>> {
     private int comp(T upper, T lower){
         return upper.compareTo(lower);
     }

     private int compare (T upper, T lower){
         return comp(upper, lower); 
     }
}
```

Comment: So we can just add the socnd type aprameter to the compare method. But it will look very unsafe. What kind of of problems we will porbably get with that?

Comment: I mean `private <T, M> int comp(Comparable<T> upper, Comparable<M> lower)`

Comment: If you want to share the type-parameters between methods, either make the type-parameter class-scoped, or introduce the same upper bound for both of them.

Comment: Good idea. That's completely satsifies my conditions. Tahnk you. I mean, your first solution.

Answer (score 4):

Because, as I said in my answer to your other question, the compiler cannot know that the two `?` stand for the same type.

The two `?` each stand for some unknown type. The `compare` method needs two `Comparable` objects for the same type `T`. If you call `compare` from the `comp` method, the compiler cannot be sure that the two `?` stand for the same type.

Comment: But what if we replace the generics with raws? What troubles we will probably get in?

Comment: If you use raw types, compiling will pass, however, you'll get a warning saying that at Runtime, a ClassCastException is likely to occur. And Generics help avoiding such errors.

Comment: When you use raw types, the compiler goes into backward compatibility mode with less type checking. But you shouldn't use raw types; see: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it/2770692)